# change reference of this keyword after importing file

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am using [react-table](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-table) to display the data. I want to keep my table column outside the react component since it is too big to put in there and reusability purpose as well. I made a table config to hold all my table config. The problem is I am using some of my local state reference in columns. So when I import column from config file it gives error where I have used `this.state`.

**tableconfig.js**

```
export const table = [
  {
    resizable: false,
    width: 50,
    Cell: ({ original }) => {
      const { pageActivity, pageNumber } = this.state;
      const currentPageActivityRow = {
        ...get(pageActivity[pageNumber], "selectedRows")
      };
      return (
        <Checkbox
          checked={currentPageActivityRow[original.id] === true}
          onChange={() => this.selectRows(original.id)}
        />
      );
    }
  },
  {
    Header: "Contact ID",
    accessor: "id"
  }
];
```

tableComponent.js

```
import {table} from '../config';
constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      pageNumber: 1,
      search: "",
      error: "",
      dialogOpen: false,
      isFilerActive: false,
      selectedFilters: {},
      pageActivity: {}
    };

    this.columns = table
  }
```

Comment: show the code where you are using `this.state` or is it `Cell` you are talking about?

Comment: make table config as function. Then you can bind this.

Answer (score 0):

maybe try binding your `table`? It has to be a function though

```
const table = () => (
[
  {
    resizable: false,
    width: 50,
    Cell: ({ original }) => {
      const { pageActivity, pageNumber } = this.state;
      const currentPageActivityRow = {
        ...get(pageActivity[pageNumber], "selectedRows")
      };
      return (
        <Checkbox
          checked={currentPageActivityRow[original.id] === true}
          onChange={() => this.selectRows(original.id)}
        />
      );
    }
  },
  {
    Header: "Contact ID",
    accessor: "id"
  }
];
)

// tableComponent.js

constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      pageNumber: 1,
      search: "",
      error: "",
      dialogOpen: false,
      isFilerActive: false,
      selectedFilters: {},
      pageActivity: {}
    };

    this.columns = table.bind(this);
  }
```